# Is it possible to use JOIN in PartiQL in Dynamo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, partiql

From the AWS guide here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Querying.html

```
SELECT ecs.state_name, f.feature_name, f.feature_class 
FROM s3_east_coast_states ecs 
JOIN ddb_features f ON ecs.state_alpha = f.state_alpha 
WHERE ecs.state_name LIKE 'New%';
```

That's definitely a JOIN. But when I run a join:

`SELECT * FROM "division-allocations-dev" da JOIN "branch-division-dev" bd ON bd.divisionID = da.divisionID where da.divisionID = 499;"`

I get this error:

> Only select from a single table or index is supported.

Now those docs are specific to EMR for Dynamo, so is a JOIN only allowed in the EMR tool? PartiQL [definitely has JOINs](https://partiql.org/tutorial.html#unnesting-nested-collections-using-join) so is Dynamo only supporting a subset of PartiQL? If so, where do I find a list of what Dynamo supports?

Comment: Those docs seem to indicate the data is being imported into hive tables and then queried after.

Comment: yes but it's the top result for "dynamodb partiql join" and Dynamo supports PartiQL and PartiQL has JOIN

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to use JOIN in PartiQL in Dynamo?

Short answer: no.

> Dynamo only supporting a subset of PartiQL?

[Yes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html#ql-reference.what-is).  The DynamoDB PartiQL subset [provides familiar syntax](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/build-faster-with-amazon-dynamodb-and-partiql-sql-compatible-operations/) consistent with the (no-join) core API.

> where do I find a list of what Dynamo supports?

See the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.statements.html). You get SELECT (no joins), UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE.